# R: How to move from an episode-year dataframe with start and end dates to a daily dataframe, carrying on certain variables?

Tags: r

I have an episode-year dataframe with an episode_id, year, start_date, end_date, and certain informative columnse. I am trying to convert this into a dataframe that lists the number of ongoing episodes per day (working!) AND keeps certain informative columns (not working).

Sample dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(episode_name = c("a", "a", "b", "c"), year = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2012), Start_date = as.Date(sample(seq(as.Date('2014/01/01'), as.Date('2015/01/01'), by="day"), 4))) %>% 
  mutate(End_date = as.Date(Start_date + sample(1:365, 4, replace = TRUE)), informative_column = c("information for episode a", "information for episode a", "information for episode b", "information for episode c"))
```

This is what the created df looks like:

[image]

Based on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982289/count-the-number-of-active-episodes-per-month-from-data-with-start-and-end-dates), I already managed to create a dataframe that lists the number of episodes per day, based on Start_date and End_date:

```
# Create a sequence of days to work with
day_seq <- function(start, end){
  seq(start, end, by = "day")
}

# Create a new DF of ongoing episodes per day
episodes_per_day <- data.frame(format(do.call("c", mapply(day_seq, df$Start_date, df$End_date),), "%Y-%m-%d",) %>% table)

# Rename the Colums to make it look nice
names(episodes_per_day)[names(episodes_per_day) == '.'] <- 'date'
names(episodes_per_day)[names(episodes_per_day) == 'Freq'] <- "sum_episodes"
```

The resulting df episodes_per_day looks like:

[image]

I don't manage however to carry the episode names with it and/or the informative columns.

Ideally, I would want to list the episode_name in one column, speratated by "," if there are multiple episodes ongoing on that day. In the same way, I would also want to carry the informative column to the new dataframe.

I would be immensely grateful for all tips! It's my first post here. If you need any additional explanations, please alert me. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Always nice to see a first post that is clear and reproducible!